# Run local script in other machine using ssh

Tags: ssh, remote, remote-access

I have a script in my local machine and i want to run it in remote machines without copy this script in each machines by using ssh.

currently I use scp to copy this script in remote machine and then run the command :

```
ssh @ip:"./script"
```

Comment: Does your script contain a list of simple commands that run one by one or some complex structures like loops?

Comment: @M.Dm. it's a loop for removing some users

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is such a solution: `ssh user@host 'bash -s' < local_script.sh`. Other examples can be found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-a-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine) page.